# What is this plant called?

Tags: identification, trees

[image]

I am doing a project about plants and I am new at this. I found this in a park in Cairo, Egypt. Would be great if someone can identify it.

Comment: Does it have a fragrance?  Was he tree apical dominant?

Comment: Need more info - was it a tree, a large shrub, a small shrub or a climber? Is it fragrant? How tall is the plant?